# Adding an Item to GridView when user clicks button using Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, gridview

I tried to create a custom Adapter that adds an item to a Grid (using GridView) at runtime, in response to a user clicking a button.

Each item added to the grid contains 2 TextView items and an ImageView Item. The text to be stored in each TextView item is provided by the user prior to clicking the button.

I couldn't find any example of how to do this online, so I just looked at examples that had custom grid adapters that initialised a grid when the app launched such as this one:

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

The only problem was that I didn't have an array of strings that I could pre-programme, because these are determined by user input at runtime, and each object added to the grid should only appear when the button is clicked, otherwise, the screen should be blank.

I tried to replace the array of strings with an ArrayList instead, and add a method that could be called after the button is clicked, which adds a String to the ArrayList, and then calls notifyDataSetChanged(); Sadly, it doesn't seem to work. See applicable code snippets as follows:

```
   private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


   public void addString(String s) {
    list.add(s);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Viewt view;

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.l, parent, false);

        view = new Viewt();

        view.tview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        convertView.setTag (view);

        } else {

        view  = (Viewt) convertView.getTag();

       }

       view.tview.setText(list.get(position));

       return convertView;
       }

    public static class Viewt {

    TextView tviewone;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing convertView.setTag(view) in your adapter and you are trying to get the view from convertView.getTag() in your adapter.

```
if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.l, parent, false);

    view = new Viewt();

    view.tview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // add below line in adapter.
    convertView.setTag (view);

    } else {

    view  = (Viewt) convertView.getTag();

   }

   view.tview.setText(list.get(position));

   return convertView;
   }
```

Comment: Hi Raman, you're right - I just added it, but it doesn't make any difference to my code working :(